# How to find the name of the active material with python

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I want to add nodes to a node group, but for that, I need to know the name of the currently selected material. How can I find the active material with python?

Comment: Do you mean 'active' as in the selected group in the node editor?

Comment: Also, do you want to find the active material or the active node group? The title is asking one thing but the question itself implies something else.

Comment: I want to know the name of the currently selected material.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is `bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name`